# javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.2 Message

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I am getting the below exception while testing my Spring WS in SOAP UI. Is anyone aware of this exception and let me know where do in need to look into the code to vanish this exception.

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.2 Message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPPart1_2Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_2Impl.java:74)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:155)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:257)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:342)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.&lt;init&gt;(SaajSoapMessage.java:117)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:186)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What does your request in soapUI look like?

Comment: How does your WSDL look like (the one you add to your SoapUI project)?

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz..  I gave a second look to the WSDL and found that I was still using the namespace for SOAP1.1 and not SOAP 1.2. With a slight change in the WSDL the service is now running fine in SOAP UI

Answer (score 3):

This can also be caused by an incorrect 'Content-Type' header; I was using `application/soap+xml` and my java based Web Service did not like it; I used `text/xml;charset=utf-8` and it seems to work OK.